# Connecting Application to Azure SignalR Service

Tags: azure, .net-core, signalr

I'm trying to connect my application to Azure SignalR Service. The application works fine using SignalR locally or even using Azure App Services.

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

The code above is what I had and everything works.

```
services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(Configuration.GetValue<string>("SignalRConnectionString"));
```

This is the change to be able to use Azure SignalR Service.
In the logs, I can see that the request is being forwarded to the Azure End Point.
I keep getting this error.

> failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available

Comment: On the `AddAzureSignalR()` try to add the connection string manually and see if it works that way first.